# IOS: Firebase Offline isPersistenceEnabled not working

Tags: ios, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using the following line in my AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
FirebaseApp.configure()
Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true
return true
}
```

Is this all I need to add to make my ReactJS app available offline? When I compile and run and test through Testflight - I turn off WIFI and use Airplane Mode and my app just returns a blank screen ... do I have to enable something else?

Answer (score 0):

The `Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true` only ensures that data that you app has recently loaded while online is also available when you call the same API next time while offline.

If the app itself doesn't load, it is unrelated to this API call and you'll want to look at how to make a React app available while offline.